# Put more keys and values into an existing array

Tags: php

I have an array like so:

```
$json = array('error'=>true);
```

But I'd like to perhaps add more keys and values to this at a later time. My feeble knowledge tried this:

```
$json .= array('something'=>'else');
```

Which doesn't work. I found `array_push` but it seems this is for just pushing in new values - not keys. How is this achieved so that with 2 separate declarations I end up with the equivalent of:

```
$json .= array('error'=>true,'something'=>'else');
```

Comment: `$json['something'] = 'else';` ?

Comment: @billyonecan lol. i feel embarrassed right now.

Comment: Time to read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: `$json = array_merge($json,array('something'=>'else'));`

Comment: $json += array('something'=>'else'); .= don't works with arrays there you must set +=.. however there are so many other variants..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many ways to accomplish this:

1. `$json['keyname'] = 'something`
2. `$json[] = 'something'` <- numerical incremented key
3. `array_push($json, 'value')` <- same as above
4. `$json = array_merge($json, $some_other_array)` <- mixes the two arrays together

Just keep in mind that arrays are not strings